# Bedeutung "auf niedriger Ebene"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, standard-german

Folgende Formulierung in einem Nachrichtentext über die Verhältnisse zwischen Ägypten und Israel verstehe ich nicht, und kann sie mir nicht mit Google Suchen und Übersetzungen helfen zu verstehen:

> Drei Tage vor dem Überfall der Hamas warnte Ägypten laut US-Angaben
> Israel vor einem Angriff aus Gaza, möglicherweise auf niedriger Ebene.

[Vollständiger Text auf tagesschau.de](https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/israel-nachbarstaaten-100.html)

Ich verstehe den letzten Teil des Satzes nicht - "möglicherweise auf niedriger Ebene".
Bedeutet es:

1. Das der Angriff vom Boden ausgeht und nicht von der Luft?
2. Das die Warnung sich bei der Bevölkerung verbreitet hat, aber es keine Warnung von offiziellen Stellen gab?
3. Das die Warnung nicht ernst genommen wurde?

Kann mir jemand helfen es zu verstehen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Da sind die administrativen Ebenen der jeweiligen Länder gemeint. Die höchste Ebene in diesem Zusammenhang wären die Staatsoberhäupter oder Regierungs-Chefs. Darunter kommen die entsprechenden Ministerien, und darunter die entsprechenden Behörden wie Polizei, Geheimdienste, etc, zuerst deren Leiter, dann die Mitarbeiter der einzelnen Abteilungen. "Auf niedriger" Ebene meint in diesem Zusammenhang, dass Mitarbeiter einer solchen Behörde mit Mitarbeitern einer Behörde des anderen Landes gesprochen haben.

In diesem konkreten Fall wird in der Meldung vermutet, dass Polizei- oder Geheimdienstmitarbeiter Ägyptens (aber vermutlich nichteinmal deren Chefs) mit ihren israelischen Kollegen auf vergleichbarer Hierarchie-Ebene in der israelischen Polizei oder dem israelischen Geheimdienst gesprochen haben und mitgeteilt, dass sie Hinweise auf vermutlich bevorstehende Aktionen der Hamas haben. Häufig wird in solchen Zusammenhängen auch von "Arbeitsebene" gesprochen, insbesondere, wenn eine solche Zusammenarbeit zwischen den Ländern offiziell vereinbart ist und regelmäßig stattfindet - was hier ggf. nicht der zutrifft.